# What happens if you, an energy that's between two energy levels for bound states, into the Schrödinger Equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation

As I understand it in Non Relativistic Quantum Mechanics bound states are only allowed at certain energy levels, and that this is the case for any potential that has bound states.  Also for some potentials, such as a finite potential well if the energy is lower than the energy at the top of the well then the state is bound.  As I understand it is possible to use the Schrödinger to find the energies for bound states.

My question is, if you don't know how to find the energies for a bound state, and so put in an energy that is between the energies of two bound states, but which is not an energy for a bound state?

Answer (score 2):

For the time-independent Schrodinger equation:

$$\hat{H}|\psi\rangle=E|\psi\rangle$$

if you require that $E$ be some value that isn't the energy of an eigenstate, then the equation will simply have **no solution**. No stationary state will have the energy that you require.

For the time-dependent Schrodinger equation:

$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle=\hat{H}|\psi(t)\rangle$$

it doesn't really make sense to "put in an energy", as there's quite simply no place to put it.

Comment: So is there just one solution to the time dependent Schrödinger Equation for the ground state of a potential, or are there multiple solutions to the time dependent Schrödinger Equation?

Comment: @AndersGustafson There is one solution for every possible initial state.